# Why is function not changing global variable even after specifying global

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I have recently started programming. Everything is working fine but this piece of code intriguing me from a long time.

Here is my code.

```
addon = 20
startup = 50 + addon

def click():
    global addon, startup
    addon *= 2
    print addon, startup

click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
click()
```

This is my output:-

```
40 70
80 70
160 70
320 70
640 70
1280 70
2560 70
5120 70
10240 70
20480 70
```

This is what I expected:-

```
40 90
80 170
160 330
320 650
640 1290
1280 2570
2560 5130
5120 10250
10240 20490
20480 40970
```

I am just not getting. if every call of `click` is updating global variable `addon` than it should also update `startup` variable. But don't know why it is not working.

Comment: @Sanatan: How should `startup` be updated? Should it also be multiplied with `2`?

Comment: actually it was `startup = 50 + addon` not `startup = 50`. Please help.

Comment: Where is the code that changes startup.  You set it to 70 and never change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startup` does not store an *expression*, it stores the *result* of an expression, **once**.

In other words, the variable `startup` references the *result* of `50 + addon`, which at the time is the integer `70`.

That `addon` later changes does not make a difference here, because `startup` does not reference `addon`.

You'd have to make `startup` a *function* instead, and call that function each time if you wanted to re-calculate the expression:

```
startup = lambda: 50 + addon
```

I used a [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to create the function here; a `lambda` creates a function from a single expression.

You then call `startup` each time you need to see the latest result:

```
def click():
    global addon
    addon *= 2
    print addon, startup()
```

Comment: thankyou, I spent a lot time searching on internet But never got the answer. Thanks a lot.